# How do I ensure org-sbe is consistently passed a string when copying tables

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table, quote

I'm trying to transform the data from one table to another however I can't do it with built in functions so I have to use org-sbe to call some elisp:

```
#+tblname: clues
|  02a8 |  0050 |  5012 |  2225 |  9555 |

#+name: hex-word-to-bitmap
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var hex='02a8
  (let ((res "")
        (number (string-to-number (prin1-to-string hex) 16)))
      (while (not (= number 0))
        (setq res (concat (if (= 1 (logand number 1)) "1" "0") res))
        (setq number (lsh number -1)))
      (if (string= res "")
          (setq res "0"))
      res))
#+end_src
```

The end result is not every number is converted when I apply the following table formula:

```
#+tblname: hex-to-bitmap
| #ERROR | 1010000 | 101000000010010 | 10001000100101 | 1011110 |
#+TBLFM: @<$<..@>$>='(org-sbe hex-word-to-bitmap (hex (identity remote(clues,@@#$$#))))
```

I thought identity should pass along the data unmolested but I don't seem to be able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's no coincidence that the numbers causing this failure contain the hex digits a-f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prin1-to-string` doesn't know what to do with `02a8`: it thinks it's a variable. Any hex digit other than 0-9 would cause the same problem. If you quote it, it works.

Obviously, the transformations that happen when you take a string out of a buffer and mangle it through `org-sbe` and in various other unnatural ways to produce another string that will be inserted somewhere else, are not obvious :-)

In this particular case, instead of using `org-sbe` with a code block, I would write a lisp function to do the transformation and evaluate the code block to add the function to the interpreter. Then reevaluate the formulas. Something like this:

```
#+tblname: clues
|  02a8  |  0050 |  5012 |  2225 |  9555 | abcd |

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun hex-to-bin (hex)
    (let ((res "")
          (number (string-to-number hex 16)))
      (while (not (= number 0))
        (setq res (concat (if (= 1 (logand number 1)) "1" "0") res))
        (setq number (lsh number -1)))
      (if (string= res "")
          (setq res "0"))
      res))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: hex-to-bin

#+tblname: hex-to-bitmap-table
| 1010101000 | 1010000 | 101000000010010 | 10001000100101 | 1001010101010101 | 1010101111001101 |
#+TBLFM: @<$<..@>$>='(hex-to-bin remote(clues,@@#$$#))
```

You can debug the function independently, use a debugger on it if things get hairy and when it's ready, you can use it in the table formula without worrying (too much) about hidden conversions.

Comment: In the end I gave up on forcing org-sbe to do the inplace thing and instead fed the table directly to an org-babel code block (as I was transforming the whole table). In previous exercises like this I usually had a cell which was a copy of the remote cell and then operated on that. I'm not sure if that would have made a difference.